# Feathersjs logger and hooks

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs

Using FeathersJS and Sequelize-MariaDB for this particular App.
The DB and Service seem OK from the basic FeathersCLI initialisation

We  then remove the logger module and replace it with our in-house version called "logger" but in ../src/utils/logger.js

We add a before-create hook to validate incoming POST data and add backend fields to the data.

We also add an additional before-find hook which checks for additional authorization returning a 401 if not given. These are the only hooks on this service (no other hooks yet on any other service.

We test using Postman.

The create hook seems to work well producing valid records in the db.

However, A get (ie. list) request returns with a

```
   {
        "name": "GeneralError",
        "message": "logger is not a function",
        "code": 500,
        "className": "general-error",
        "data": {},
        "errors": {}
    }
```

the above message does no make sense! Our logger function works perfectly when called. We have tested that in ../app and in the ../src/services/myservice/myservice.service and in the two hooks and is not called anywhere else in our codebase.

So where is the above error coming from?
Is some other node_module triggering it? (outside our control)

Comment: @Daff  Thanks for your response but I don't think so, as the require line at the top of app.js L6 has been updated to point to our logger module in ../utils/logger.js which has the same export name. so the line at L51 should be using the changed one right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort of solved (well not really) but must get on, so we have removed logger.js from app so the error goes away and replaced with good old console.log() when needed. so we can also remove winston which I've never been a fan of ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry. Exactly as stated I have completely removed all logger from the app, both ours and the original. unsurprisingly this fixes the problem conflict. If it was being used inside Feathers then I guess it still is being loaded and used internally but its absence from the app seems to be irrelevant and we can replace with good old console.log

Answer (score 1):

The only other place the logger is used by default is in the Express errorHandler (see https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/crow/src/app.js#L51) which will need to be updated accordingly.